# Write out stale data from ext4 fs, once a disk has become available again

Tags: filesystems, lvm, read-only

This is about an ext4 filesystem on a logical volume managed with LVM on a LUKS encryption on a hardware RAID. The operating system is a generic Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

The RAID unfortunately failed recently and the filesystem was re-mapped read only at that time. After stopping all the applications writing to that file system, the RAID could be fully restored with some good luck. And, with even more luck, the file system is still fully readable with the restored data! And `e2fsck` didn't even find errors.

So is everything fine? Unfortunately, not. Unfortunately, there is quite an amount (hundreds of Megabytes) of unwritten data still lingering in the memory and I don't know how to get that out to the disk. That's why I have not rebooted yet, and that's also why I don't want to reboot, because repairing all the database files with that missing data will be a major work. The presence of the unwritten data can easily be verified via:

```
sync ; grep Dirty /proc/meminfo
```

which usually yields only a few kilobytes, but gives hundred of Megabytes in my case. Unfortunately, I don't know, at which level of the various kernel drivers that data is hanging around: physical disk cache, one of the volume groups, or the actual file system.

### Repairs tried so far

My first attempt has been to re-mount the still read-only file system as read-write via:

```
mount -o remount /dev/mapper/vg1-data
```

Unfortunately, this yields the error message:

```
mount: /data: cannot remount /dev/mapper/vg1-data read-write, is write-protected.
```

However, the actual volume is read-write, as can be verified by:

```
cat /sys/block/dm-*/ro
```

which gives the result `0` for everything under the control of the device mapper, including the volumes on top of the RAID. The same is true for the actual `sd` device itself. Furthermore:

```
dmsetup info vg1-data
```

reports the volume's state as `ACTIVE`. It would instead report the state as `ACTIVE (READ-ONLY)`, if it was read-only. Similarly, `lvs` shows normal attributes of `-wi-ao----`.

**A large clue**, that the read-write capability of the file system is actually NOT the source of the problem, is available via `tune2fs -l`. This prints, among many other stats, this information about the last error on the mounted file system:

```
Last error time:          Wed Jan 17 18:47:43 2024
Last error function:      ext4_remount
Last error line #:        5822
Last error err:           EBUSY
```

At the time of that error, there is this cryptic line written to the syslog:

```
EXT4-fs error (device dm-N): ext4_remount:5822: comm mount: Abort forced by user
```

When I explicitely force the volume to read-only mode via:

```
dmsetup table vg1-data | dmsetup reload -r vg1-data
dmsetup resume vg1-data
dmsetup info vg1-data
```

then further re-`mount` attempts do NOT update that "Last error time" timestamp anymore, but yield the same (and now obviously correct) error message. After I used `dmsetup` again to make the volume read-write, then further re-`mount` attempts will update the timestamp of the Last error again and also write to syslog again.

On another serverfault posting, I found the hint to set the disk mapper volumes to read-only and then back to read-write, but that also did not do the trick: [Linux software RAID 1 - root filesystem becomes read-only after a fault on one disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/52067/linux-software-raid-1-root-filesystem-becomes-read-only-after-a-fault-on-one-d)

`cryptsetup reload` also achieved nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `lvs`   LV attributes will indicate whether the read only is an LVM thing or lower level storage.

Comment: If you want to save all the data, even the one which is written in memory/cache, attach a large enough external USB disk and copy all data to it. `e2fsck` is only able to guarantee a consistent filesystem, it doesn't guarantee that all files are sill okay. If `e2fsck` finds an filesystem error, it fixes this error by removing the faulty parts of the filesystem (moving the broken remains to `/lost+found`). I hope for you you've used that tool in read only mode, otherwise it might have destroyed data.

Comment: PS if you want to save your data you should stop experimenting and never use any tools which might write anything, it's just foolish, either you know what you are doing or you don't know...

Comment: @paladin Sorry, that I am talking about a server with a "hardware RAID" in my question should have told you, that I have more data to handle here, than will fit on standard USB disks. And yes, I have a backup thousands of kilometers away, but I am lazy to reinstall everything, if it is not necessary.

Comment: Then use an USB JBOD array :p (BTRFS works here best, as it's very easy to setup. Just like so: `mkfs.btrfs -L usbdiskarray /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd` (this will create a single BTRFS filesystem) and mounting just with `mount -L usbdiskarray /mnt/` PS you don't need to use same disks, just get as many working disks as you need and just attach these things to your server PPS you could also just hotplug some SATA drives (a bit dangerous, first plug SATA, then power), but for that you need to open the server